# @Autowired Spring NullPointerException Null Beans after ApplicationContext Creation

Tags: java, spring

When I create my `ApplicationContext` the myBean Constructors are used successfully.
But after creation the beans are `null` using `@Autowired` tag.

I though `@Autowired` would replace `getBean()` somehow? Am I getting this wrong?

**Why do I need to call GetBean, when I already created my Beans (during ApplicationContext startup) and also Autowired them?**

Here is what I have done so far:

Main:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.somePackage")
public class Main {
    ApplicationContext ctx= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

    SomeBean myBean = ctx.getBean(SomeBean.class);
    myBean.doSomething();//succeeds

    AnyOtherClass aoc = new AnyOtherClass();//Nullpointer (see AnyOtherClass.class for details)

}
```

AnyOtherClass:

```
public class AnyOtherClass {
    @Autowired
    protected SomeBean someBean;

    public AnyOtherClass(){
        someBean.doSomething();//Nullpointer
    }
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SomeBean BeanSomeBean() {
        return new SomeBean();
    }
}
```

MyBean:

```
public class SomeBean {
    public SomeBean (){}
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("do Something..");
    }
}
```

Note: Interface `ApplicationContextAware` works fine but without `@Autowired`. And I would really like to go with `@Autowired` since it sounds more comfortable and less errorprone to me.

Comment: make `AnyOtherClass` have `@Component` annotation and make sure the autoscan sees it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `@Autowired` to work in `AnyOtherClass`, `AnyOtherClass` needs to be a Spring bean.
Something like this

*AppConfig*

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SomeBean BeanSomeBean() {
        return new SomeBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public AnyOtherClass BeanAnyOtherClass() {
        return new AnyOtherClass();
    }
}
```

*Main*

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.somePackage")
public class Main {
    ApplicationContext ctx= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

    SomeBean myBean = ctx.getBean(SomeBean.class);
    myBean.doSomething();//succeeds

    AnyOtherClass aoc = ctx.getBean(AnyOtherClass.class);

}
```

If you instantiate a class using `new AnyOtherClass()`, **it will bypass Spring and none of the annotations will work**. You must get it out of Spring context in order for it to be a Spring bean.

Comment: I declear it as a Bean in AppConfig, which I load in Main.class. Or do you mean to define it as a Bean in both places (AppConfig & AnyOtherClass)?

Comment: @Hansa Just to be clear on what I meant, I'm not talking about `SomeBean` class, but the class which injects it using `@Autowired`. So, `SomeBean` is already a Spring bean (declared in `AppConfig`), but `AnyOtherClass` also needs to be a Spring bean (declared in `AppConfig`, or annotated with `@Component`, located in a package which is scanned (`com.somePackage`))

Comment: Hmm that would mean for me I add `@autowired static AnyOtherClass aoc` to Main. (`static` because its in main..)
Then I get: BeanCreationException->BeanInstantiationException-> nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Hansa I don't think you understood me, check my updated answer.

Comment: so `@Autowired` helps me to find Beans in Beans, but the first bean I have to get with getBean()? --> therefore @Autowired does not replace the getBean() fully?!

I am a bit confused because, during Creating the ApplicationContext the beans are already created. And then I have to get them via getBean() again although I Autowired them... It seems like I expected to much from Autowired

Comment: @Hansa Depends on the kind of application you are building (for example, you won't need this in web app), but yes, if you need a bean in a class which is not a bean, you need to get it from context using `getBean()`.

Comment: ok thx for your answer as well as your patience

Comment: @Hansa NP, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Component
public class AnyOtherClass {
@Autowired
protected SomeBean someBean;

public AnyOtherClass(){
    someBean.doSomething();//Nullpointer
}
```

Besides, you need to make sure this class is in com.somePackage package.

Comment: thanks for your response - but changes nothing for me =(